# How to show the same DialogFragment twice or more

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

My application has a button that shows a custom `DialogFragment` when the user presses a button. The `DialogFragment` is shown like this:

```
    if(searchDialog == null)
    {
        searchDialog = new SearchElementDialog();
        searchDialog.setOnItemClickListener(searchElementItemClickListener);
    }

    searchDialog.show (getFragmentManager(), "SearchElement");
```

When the user is finished `dismiss` is called in the usual way and the dialog is removed. Now, when the user presses the same button again I want to show the same dialog, in the same visible state as when the user left it, calling the code in the first block above does display the dialog and its visual state is restored, but:

The screen is not dimmed, and pressing outside of the dialog does not dismiss it and neither are the controls behind it responding.

The dialog does not move when the softkeyboard comes into view.

On the first showing everything is fine. Is it not possible to show the same instance of a dialog again?

Answer (score 1):

What if you hide and show the dialog instead of the whole fragment.

When you want to dismiss call:

```
searchDialog.getDialog().dismiss();
```

and when you want to show it:

```
searchDialog.getDialog().show();
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this doesn't work. getDialog returns null unless the dialog is already visible so I can't use it to call show. If I call getDialog().dismiss() and searchDialog.show() the result is the same.

Comment: @CurlyPaul Yes when you instantiate it is shown automatically, but when you hide with `getDialog().dismiss()`, I'm pretty sure you can show it later with `getDialog.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simas was partly right. `getDialog()` doesn't return `null` when the `Dialog` is shown but it does when there is no `Dialog` displayed. I stored it as a field in my class

`mDialog = getDialog()`

and subsequently called

`mDialog.show()`

which worked every time.